# Randomizing the population of a ListView using a Cursor, from a SQLite 3 Database ...

Tags: android, listview, random, simplecursoradapter

I'd like to find the BEST way to populate an **Android ListView** from a (very small < 50 records) database in a **RANDOM** fashion, meaning that each time I re-query the data from the SQLLite 3 DB, it populates the ListView in a *different random order*.

I'm setting the listview in the standard way: (a) populate a DBCursor via a DB Query, (b) populate a SimpleCursorAdapter with it's normal inputs, and finally (c) set the Listview Adapter.

Pseudo Code:

```
DBCursor = db.query();     
cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.xml-file, DBCursor, DB_Columns, db_to);    
listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

What I think might be a possible solution is to tweek the DB.Query() statement somehow:

```
db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having , orderBy);
```

The question is exactly 'what' to tweek and 'how' to syntactically do it. Or, is this really the best place for interrogation or is the resulting Cursor a better place to implement a solution?

Many thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research and experimentation I have found something useful as a solution:

Instead of using Androids pre-Compiled Query statements of the form:

```
db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
```

I used a db.rawQuery instead which permitted a more flexible SQL statement.

```
db.rawQuery("select * from catstory ORDER BY RANDOM()", null);
```

the Eclipse IDE takes that statement w/out error, compiles and runs as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Specify "random()" as orderBy in query. random() it's a sqlite core function. You can read about it here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Comment: I like this approach. The problem now is that Android Precomiles it's query statement:

db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy)

... and then the Eclipse IDE kicks out an error of the sort:

'random()' is undefined .....

Comment: After some more research and experimentation I have something useful as a solution:


Instead of using Androids pre-Compiled Query statements of the form:


    db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);


I used a db.rawQuery instead which permitted a more flexible SQL statement.


    db.rawQuery("select * from catstory ORDER BY RANDOM()", null);


the Eclipse IDE takes that statement w/out error, compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: I think you try something like 
`db.query(..., random());` instead of `db.query(..., "random()");`

Comment: I did try that and quite a few variations on that theme. The one thing which worked was this syntax: db.rawQuery("select * from catstory ORDER BY RANDOM()", null);